# Comparing UUIDs in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, uuid

Let's say I create two tables in Postgres with `UUID` as the `PRIMARY KEY`. These `UUID` are generated using the `uuid-ossp` module in Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/uuid-ossp.html

```
CREATE TABLE f(  
    idFoo UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    foo TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    idBar UUID,
    bar text,
    FOREIGN KEY (idBar) REFERENCES foo(idFoo)
);
```

I then want to create a VIEW based on the above two tables:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW foobar AS (
     SELECT fooid, barid
     FROM foo, bar
     WHERE f.idFoo = b.idBar
     -- AND some other condition --
 );
```

**Question**: How do I compare the `UUID` types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't compare UUID, you're looking to JOIN on them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW foobar AS (
   SELECT f.foo, b.bar, f.id 
     FROM f JOIN b USING (id)
    WHERE  -- some other condition --
);
```

To JOIN on different columns, you can:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW foobar AS (
   SELECT f.foo, b.bar, idFoo, idBar 
     FROM f JOIN b ON (idFoo = idBar)
    WHERE  -- some other condition --
);
```

(Of course, because idFoo = idBar, there's no need to include both in your second select).

Comment: What about the case when the `PRIMARY KEY` is named different (updated the question)?

Comment: Q: "How do I do X?" A:"Here's how you do Y." Classic SO.